# how to identifying updated child event in series(rucurring events) with help of calendar graph api?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I m syncing outlook calendar with my other system using graph apis.
Issue - If a single event gets modified in series of events in outlook, I am not able to identify that changed one only.
fields in response feed- like updateddatetime, changekey are not help in this scenario? Is there any specific way or api or suggestion?

Comment: Have you [look at delta query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-events?tabs=http)?

Comment: Yes, but it will not help to identify exact child event in series updated recently.https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserEmail}}/calendarView/delta?startDateTime=2021-06-01T00:00:00.4972765Z&endDateTime=2021-06-10T00:00:00.4972765Z&$deltaToken=latest